# How to make Dropbox indicator working in Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: indicator, dropbox

the Dropbox indicator doesn't work anymore in Ubuntu 15.10.
Tried installing appindicator1 and restarting dropbox, but still no indicator appears. How to get it working?

Answer (score 2):

This one

Worked in Ubuntu 16.04 lts Flashback Compiz

1. Kill dropbox, and restart it so it shows

   ```
   dropbox stop && env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity dropbox start
   ```

   If it works
2. Go to the settings in dropbox after it starts up and select to not start at startup.
3. Go to Applications > Preferences > Startup Applications and click on add and

Enter

Name:       Dropbox

Command:    env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity dropbox start

Comment:    Sync your files across computers and to the web

and save

Comment: [See here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029225/how-to-fix-broken-nautilus-dropbox-icon-in-ubuntu-18-04-gnome-flashback-in-top-p/1030775#1030775)

Answer (score 1):

Something which worked for me was

1. `apt-get install nautilus-dropbox`
2. check that it worked with Unity but not with the environment I'm using
   (gnome-fallback, it used to work with it before at least with 14.04),
3. check that it worked under gnome-fallback with

   ```
   dropbox stop && XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity dropbox start
   ```

   (gnome-fallback used to have XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity, in 15.10 it has a prefix before Unity).
4. Create a file `~/scripts/startDropbox` (and ensure it is executable with `chmod 755 ~/scripts/startDropbox`)

   ```
   #! /bin/sh    
   set +e

   if expr "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" : '.*Unity' > /dev/null ; then
       export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity
   fi
   # yes, ! is counter intuitive here
   if ! dropbox running ; then
       dropbox stop
   fi
   dropbox start -i
   ```
5. Create a `~/.config/autostart/my-dropbox.desktop` (dropbox will overwrite your changes if you try to modify ~/.config/autostart/dropbox.desktop)

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Dropbox
   GenericName=File Synchronizer
   Comment=Sync your files across computers and to the web
   Exec=/home/AProgrammer/scripts/startDropbox
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   Icon=dropbox
   Categories=Network;FileTransfer;
   StartupNotify=false
   ```

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, but as Ubuntu 15.10 had few another problems, I've installed back version 14.04 Therefore I am not able to try this solution now.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install libappindicator1
```

Log out, and then log back in and use:

```
dropbox stop && dropbox start
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I have tried, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

For what's it worth I solved this problem by running 'dropbox stop' then 'dropbox start'in my list of startup programs in Ubuntu 15.10. I took care, even though it might be unnecessary, to use the STOP option first. The indicator then shows correctly and syncing works.