# Ubuntu 18.04 - Dropbox icon won't show / stay

Tags: 18.04, icons, dropbox

my machine automatically updated to Ubuntu 18.04, and the Dropbox icon won't show up in the system tray area in the top right (I think Ubuntu calls them appindicators). I often used the icon shortcut to choose which folders to sync (few times a week for web development). So, how do I the icons to show? Also, is there another way to get to Dropbox settings on Ubuntu?

When I reinstall Dropbox, the icons come back but go away when I reboot.

Let me know if you need more info to troubleshoot.

Thanks.

Comment: Shoot, just saw this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065714/how-to-fix-broken-dropbox-menu-in-xubuntu-18-04

I'll try this when I get home and update this post accordingly.

Comment: What is your desktop environment?