# How to fix broken dropdown menu of HPLIP tray icon in Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, mate, 18.10, system-tray, hplip

I have installed Ubuntu MATE 18.04.1 LTS with all updates.

Here I have installed HPLIP GUI with

```
sudo apt install hplip-gui
```

Then I after reboot I have `hp-systray` in the tray (indicator applet), but its dropdown menu is not functioning:

> [image: hp-systray not showing dropdown menu]

How can I fix this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The autostart file from `hplip-gui` is located in `/etc/xdg/autostart/hplip-systray.desktop`.

To fix the menu display we need to launch hplip with help of DBus (as in [DropBox case](https://askubuntu.com/a/1065718/66509)) by creating a custom copy of this file for the user:

```
killall hp-systray
rm ~/.hplip/hp-systray.lock
mkdir -p ~/.config/autostart/
cp /etc/xdg/autostart/hplip-systray.desktop ~/.config/autostart/
sed -i "s/hp-systray -x/dbus-launch hp-systray -x/" ~/.config/autostart/hplip-systray.desktop
```

and then reboot and enjoy:

> [image: hp-systray with dropdown menu]

**Notes:**
This method is useful for 18.04 LTS, 18.10, 19.04 and 19.10. It is a temporary fix for [bug 1810745](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1810745).