# HP Envy 4500 randomly disconnecting

Tags: drivers, printing

I have been using my HP Envy 4500 with my laptop running Ubuntu as the only OS for years now. The printer is connected via WiFi to my Fritzbox modem with a fixed IP address and I am running Ubuntu 19.10 on the laptop. I do not print a lot, maybe a couple of times a week. Sometimes the printer prints but just as often as not I get the message "Error connecting to printer". This is the log entry when it doesn't print:

> prnt/backend/hp.c 824: ERROR: open device failed stat=12:
>   hp:/net/ENVY_4500_series?hostname=HPXXXXXXXXXXXX.local

One other thing, when I boot-up I get an error message from HPLIP Status Service saying:

> No system tray detected on this system.   Unable to start, exiting.

Comment: Do you have `hplip` and `hplip-gui` installed? How did you install them? What is your desktop environment?

Comment: @N0rbert Both hplip and hplip-gui are installed. "hplip ist schon die neueste Version (3.19.6+dfsg0-1ubuntu1). hplip-gui ist schon die neueste Version (3.19.6+dfsg0-1ubuntu1)." I can't remember how I installed them.

Comment: Your version looks like normal [deb-packaged version](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=hplip) for yours 19.10 release. About tray icon - it is a bug between modern [GNOME and HPLIP](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hplip/+bug/1714659).

Comment: @N0rbert I have run the setup from your link.

Comment: @N0rbert Rebooted and printer seems to be working now. I will keep testing it tomorrow but I have a good feeling that your setup suggestion worked. Is there any way to get rid of the tray warning?

Comment: I'm not sure about the GNOME , but for example MATE have better support of HPLIP tray icon, but [workaround](https://askubuntu.com/a/1107774/66509) is needed even here.

Comment: @N0rbert Your comment with a link to setting up the hplip seems to have been deleted. Since setting my printer up as per your link I have had no problems with it disconnecting. If you would include that link in an answer I will accept it as an answer to my question.